# Why does ValueTuple use non-standard IComparable implementation?

Tags: c#, icomparable, valuetuple

The documentation for [ValueTuple.IComparable.CompareTo(Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple.system-icomparable-compareto?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_ValueTuple_System_IComparable_CompareTo_System_Object_) says it returns:

> 0 if other is a ValueTuple instance; otherwise, 1 if other is null.

This makes the `IComparable` implementation seemingly useless other than perhaps not breaking code that might expect the interface to be implemented. The older reference `Tuple` class does follow the standard implementation (although it might only work if the items support `IComparable`).

The documentation says `IComparable` indicates the type can be sorted, which is not the case with `ValueTuple`:

> This interface is implemented by types whose values can be ordered or
>   sorted. It requires that implementing types define a single method,
>   CompareTo, that indicates
>   whether the position of the current instance in the sort order is
>   before, after, or the same as a second object of the same type. (...)
>
> The implementation of the CompareTo method must
>   return an Int32 that has one of three values, as shown
>   in the following table.
>
> **Less than zero** The current instance
>   precedes the object specified by the
>   CompareTo method in the sort order.
>
> **Zero** This current instance occurs in the same position in the sort
>   order as the object specified by the
>   CompareTo method.
>
> **Greater than
>   zero** This current instance follows the object specified by the
>   CompareTo method in the sort order.

So my questions are:

- Why doesn't `ValueTuple` implement `CompareTo` like Tuple does?
- And why does it implement `IComparable` even though it doesn't support meaningful sorting?

Comment: Might it have to do with the fact that you're looking at the empty ValueTuple type instead of one of its generic variants?

Comment: @BoltClock Yep, that would explain it. Whoops, didn't notice that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The non-generic ValueTuple represents an empty tuple. Since ValueTuple is a struct, that means every ValueTuple instance is equal, and so a collection of nothing but empty ValueTuples doesn't need to be sorted.

Comparing a ValueTuple to null returns 1 for the same reason comparing an empty string to null returns 1 — because you're comparing something to nothing :)

The generic variants of ValueTuple that represent tuples of one or more elements all implement `IComparable.CompareTo()` the way you would expect.

Note that Tuple itself is a static class, whereas all of its generic variants represent non-empty tuples. Tuple just contains factory methods for its non-empty variants.